Issue with Dynamic Dark Mode Switching in Codename One - Border Remains White
Hello Codename One Team!
I am implementing a dark mode feature. The dark mode works fine when the app is restarted, but when I switch to dark mode dynamically (without restarting the app), the border remains white. This issue gets resolved only after a full restart of the app. It happened only in Apple devices.
if (DeviceInfo.darkMode) {
    CN.setDarkMode(true);
    UIManager.initFirstTheme("/" +"dark-theme");

} else {
    CN.setDarkMode(false);
    UIManager.initFirstTheme("/" +"theme");
}

if (followPageController != null) followPageController.getFormController().getView().refreshTheme();
if (matchesPageController != null) matchesPageController.getFormController().getView().refreshTheme();
if (newspaperPageController != null) newspaperPageController.getFormController().getView().refreshTheme();
if (chatPageController != null) chatPageController.getFormController().getView().refreshTheme();
if (rankPageController != null) rankPageController.getFormController().getView().refreshTheme();
if (aiPageController != null) aiPageController.getFormController().getView().refreshTheme();
if (msgCenterPageController != null) msgCenterPageController.getFormController().getView().refreshTheme();


Thank you so much in advance. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Best Regards,
Oscar

How do you switch to dark mode? Do you change device settings or is there a button to toggle this? If it doesn't happen in the simulator or Android I'm guessing it's part of a native area that's outside of the application surface.

@ShaiAlmog Thank you for your quick response. I switch to dark mode within the application itself via a button toggle. The issue occurs on Apple devices and in the simulator. I have managed to fix the issue for most components by adding the background-color CSS clause to the components that were inheriting it in light mode. However, I am still unable to resolve the issue with the border of the app itself, which remains white when switching to dark mode dynamically.

When you say simulator you mean our simulator or the iOS native simulator. If it is our simulator you can see the component hierarchy in the component inspector and see which component is still white in said hierarchy to debug this.

I edited the question adding the screen from the Codename One simulator running from a PC. I also tried to add CSS code for Form and ContentPane without success.

Press the + sign in the simulator to see the full size skin, sometimes the scaling produces artifacts. Select Form in the tree and then travel down through the hierarchy to see the underlying component settings. If a component has a margin then it can't be the responsible component. Once you find one of the responsible components list their CSS for both light and dark mode here.

Try to disable the border of parent Container or Form by setting its uiid in CSS and adding attribute border: none to the uiid
